# iOS horizontal and vertical Scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am new to iOS and exploring various facets of this. I am looking to create a `UITableView` with each cell of the table view having a horizontal scrolling table view. I am new to iOS.

My custom class inheriting from `UITableViewCell` will contain a `UITableView` property. What next ?

I have dragged a TableView into the Prototype Cell of my Table View. This table view in my TableView cell will need to horizontal scrolling. I have created a `IBOutlet` for the TableView in my class inheriting from `UITableViewCell`. How can i tell that this class will be the `UITableViewDelegate`,`UITableViewDataSource` of this inner table view ?

[image]

Am I on the right path ? I am using storyboards and `iOS 7`.

Comment: iOs doesnt support this kind of design. It leads to alot of bugs. You will have to put table view in scroll view, but then you will start getting issues with gestures overlapping. This approach is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You simply specify that the UITableViewCell subclass conforms to the delegate/datasource protocols the same as you would if this was within a view controller. From there, you link the table's delegate/datasource properties to the cell.

However, I recommend you use the [UICollectionView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=wPqXU9QhyOSwBJ6-gbgP&usg=AFQjCNHHkaEit5z4PL8vj3-HxVMG9kNVEA&sig2=b1tri-AOIMSZW3TqWdngGw&bvm=bv.68693194,d.cWc) class for your horizontal sculling needs, it will make the entire process a lot less painful. My first point applies when using UICollectionView as well.

For example:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDatasource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end
```

Comment: I have done that. But how to connect the inner table view to the class. You usually drag from the table view to a controller to connect the delegate and data source. I have opened the assistant editor and dragging from the inner table view to the BIDTableViewCell, but nothing happens.

Comment: My question is how to connect the table view in the prototype cell to the BIDTableViewCell class. Control dragging to the class does not do anything.

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Have you specified in Interface Builder that the cell is a subclass of UITableViewCell, and not a UITableViewCell? If not, what you're going to want to do is open the "Document Outline" and navigate to the cell and select it. (this is to make sure you select the cell, and not its contentView) Then you're going to want to navigate to the "Identity Inspector" on Xcode's right side menu (3rd tab). In the box that says "class", type in your subclasses name to replace "UITableViewCell".

Comment: Yes i have done that. You mean to say BIDTableViewCell

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Interesting. Perhaps as screenshot of your connections inspector with the cell highlighted?